# How can I change the file location of my windows oneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I (desperately)need to have my oneDrive 'location' pointed to the correct path.  My computer was re-imaged about a month ago and I noticed the folks who serviced my computer misspelled my Admin folder. That is where my oneDrive is.  Everything worked fine because thats where my oneDrive was pointed from the re-image to but the misspelling was bothering me.  I finally got around to changing the name(it was a real pain). So now:
`C:\Users\Admin` is correct.  However, when I right-click onedrive, properties, it says its location is:
`C:\Users\wrongName`

I think this is why my oneDrive icon is not showing up in the taskbar any and everything I've read says that where to go.  I try dragging/dropping my file I have locally but I get "sharing erros".  Can anyone help me change the path of my oneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by re setting up oneDrive.  I found OneDriveSetup.exe in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\Update
```

From there I simply when through the set up process.  Thus far everything seems to be working correctly :)

Comment: Submitting a link, to a YouTube video, is not an acceptable answer. Please describe, in written words, exactly what you did.

Comment: Actually you can just unlink your computer and then reconnect it. It’s in the OneDrive settings.